# Error in strings: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: android, string, error-handling

I encountered the "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" error when trying to implement `setHeadline()` in the below code.

```
private void setupAdaptater() {
  mPostAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < Post, PostViewHolder > (
    Post.class,
    R.layout.item_layout_post,
    PostViewHolder.class,
    mPostRef
  ) {
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, int position) {
      StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.getImageUrl());
      Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(viewHolder.postIV);
      viewHolder.setHeadline(model.setHeadline()); //Headline
      viewHolder.setNumLikes(model.getNumLikes());
      viewHolder.postLikeIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          updateNumLikes(model.getUID());
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

//...

```
   public void setHeadline(String headline){ //Headline
        postHeadline.setText(String.valueOf(headline)); //This string gives the value of headline_event
    }
```

and I define the string like this:

```
public class Post {
  private String headline; //Set headline as String;

  public Post() {

  }

  public Post(String headline) {
    this.headline = headline; //This is the headline that was added
  }

  public void setHeadline(String headline) { //Set the headline
    this.headline = headline; //set the headline as string
  }
```

//..

I don't get where there is a mismatch in the  length. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Post` class, I see this code:

> ```
> public void getHeadline(String headline) { //Set the headline
>   this.headline = headline; //set the headline as string
> }
> ```

It looks like you have perhaps made a typo here: the method is **g**etHeadline but it looks like a "setter" and so should be named **s**etHeadline.

I'd expect to see two methods that look like this:

```
public String getHeadline() {
  return headline;
}

public void setHeadling(String headline) {
  this.headline = headline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben. That helped, but it moved the error to another line. Please see the edit

Comment: Call `post.setHeadline("f");`

Comment: Typo solved. Still not working. The "f" is underlined and it is written this: setHeadline() in Post cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: @Physther it still sounds like you're mixing up your getter and your setter. You should call **g**etHeadline when you want to access the existing headline (and this method doesn't take any parameters), and you should call **s**etHeadline when you want to change the headline (and this method takes one parameter: the new headline to set). See my updated answer for getter + setter implementation.

Comment: I see. It makes sense. I will try and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you so much for the informative answer.

Comment: @BenP., one more question, please. What should it be in the brackets of "post.getHeadline()"? If I leave it empty, it doesn't write on the database and if I add a string between quotation marks, it doesn't work.